# Understand the table relationship from sql scripted generated by MySql

Tags: mysql, database-schema

There are four tables, two main tables, "Page" and "Category", and two relationship tables, "category_page" and "page_category".

What's the relationship between the Category and Page tables? What does this say in the relationship tables?

```
  KEY `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` (`id`),
  KEY `FK71E8D943BB482769` (`id`)
```

The following are full schema:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Category`
--
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pageId` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pageId` (`pageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `Page`
--

CREATE TABLE `Page` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pageId` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pageId` (`pageId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `category_pages`
--
CREATE TABLE `category_pages` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) default NULL,
  KEY `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` (`id`),
  KEY `FK71E8D943BB482769` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `page_categories`
--
CREATE TABLE `page_categories` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) default NULL,
  KEY `FK72FB59CC1E350EDD` (`id`),
  KEY `FK72FB59CC75DCF4FA` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that someone is *trying* to establish a many-to-many relation between `Category` and `Page`, although there're no declarative constraints to enforce it. `category_pages` and `page_categories` appear identical, so one of them is redundant, as is the second `KEY` index on the other.

The strings like `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` are simply names for the indexes. The `FK` prefix suggests it *might* be *intended* for a foreign key constraint, but as I said, there's no declarative constraint to enforce it.

Older versions of MySQL (< 5, I think) did not enforce foreign keys, and the MyISAM storage engine (which used to be the default) still does not. This schema may be from one of those earlier versions, so the designer may have omitted the constraint declarations in a misguided effort at brevity. In any case the FK relation is necessarily *implemented* in the app layer, but relying *solely* on the app for constraint *enforcement* is generally a Bad Idea, since it has to be enforced separately in each application, and it's far too easy to get lazy and leave it out with the intention of going back later to fix it.

Comment: "category_pages" and "pages_category" may not be the same? Since one allows you to search 'categories' given a page, and the other allows you to search all "pages" given a category. So are they really redundant?

Comment: I was going by the column names, but the entire mess is not very well designed. (I hope it's not your design. ;) A proper intersection table would allow you to search in either direction.

Comment: Not my design. Without foreign relationship, how can it point to the main table "Page" and "Category" in searching the database? That's what I am wondering, if the "FK..." doesn't mean foreign key.

Comment: I think I misspoke when I said "not being used." What I should have said is that the foreign key relationship is not being *enforced.* Older versions of MySQL (< 5, I think) did not enforce foreign keys, and this schema may be from one of those earlier versions, so the designer may have omitted the constraint declarations in a misguided effort at brevity. In any case the FK relation is necessarily *implemented* in the app layer, but relying *solely* on the app for constraint *enforcement* is generally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any foreign key relationship between those tables. Purpose of following code is to define index for `id` column. I do not know the intention but one of them is redundant index.

```
KEY `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` (`id`),
KEY `FK71E8D943BB482769` (`id`)
```

Comment: Does the "FK..." means it is a foreign key to another table? Since it's created automatically, this seems not transparent to readers.

Comment: No, it is name of the index. Foreign key relationship is created using FOREIGN KEY and REFERENCES keyword. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

```
KEY `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` (`id`),
KEY `FK71E8D943BB482769` (`id`)
```

Right know these are simple index and not foreign keys, Fk... used as a prefix to understand that it is foreign keys but not foreign keys itself till there is no mapping of child and master table like below-

```
CONSTRAINT `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Category` (`id`)...
```

Whenever we create foreign key then it automatically create an index on which field we are creating foreign key, so finally foreign key should look like as per below-

```
KEY `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK71E8D943E46A97CC` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Category` (`id`)...
```

Here, it seems some one tried to create foreign key but then remove foreign key. As mysql will delete your foreign key but will not delete index so they remain in table.

Now as you have duplicate index on same field id in your table so you should remove them even you should remove both index and create primary key on id field to get better performance if you are not keeping duplicate/null values in this field.

Comment: I don't think the index is duplicated. The two "id" are different from two different tables, Category and Page, as you can see, so the indexes are totally different. Maybe they should rename them to "category_id" and "page_id", and that would make things clearer. I am new to database design, and this is what I am thinking. Any further thought?

Comment: As here it is not using for foreign keys means simply there are 2 index on same field i.e. id, so they are duplicate. Don't be confused between foreign keys and index.